# Strange debug results in R Studio

Tags: r, rstudio

I must predicate this by saying that I am still quite new to RStudio/R so I hope this is not user error. However when debugging I am getting some strange results whilst in debug mode.

1) The code jumps to another part of the code without apparently being called.

2) When this happens the highlighter only partially highlights the code it jumps to but the arrow in the margin points to this partially highlighted line

3) The code then returns to place it jumped away from originally

I get the warning "Debug location is approximate because source source code is not available". Is this related to the problem?

You can replicate the results by installing the package dlm:

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dlm/dlm.pdf

```
 p<-3
 G=diag(c(0.9963,0.9478,0.7740))
 W=diag(c(0.0026^2,0.0027^2,0.0035^2))
 C0_est=solve(diag(p)-G%*%t(G))*W
 mod2<-dlm(m0=c(0.0501,-0.0251,-0.0116),C0=C0_est,FF=X,V=0.000000001*diag(m),GG=diag(c(0.9963,0.9478,0.7740)),W=diag(c(0.0026^2,0.0027^2,0.0035^2)))
 debugonce(dlmForecast)
 dlmForecast(mod2, nAhead=5, sampleNew=2)
```

When you step through using F10 you will find that the code jumps to L7 from Lines 28,32, 54 and 57 and to L4 from line 47.

Q1.) Why does this partial highlighting of the line being debugged mean?

Q2.) What causeses the code to jump backward and forwards like this with no apparent function call?

Kind Regards

Baz

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most R packages don't include copies of the package's source code (the `keep.source` option controls this behavior; you can read more about it [here](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-devel/R-exts.html)). When you debug code from this kind of package, RStudio has to guess at both what the code looked like originally and where the current execution point is in that code. This process includes some heuristics and does occasionally misinterpret the execution point. So what you're seeing is not the actual execution point jumping around, but RStudio making the wrong guess about where it is in the deparsed code.

Code from your own R scripts (and from packages with `keep.source`) have source references (see [R journal article](http://journal.r-project.org/archive/2010-2/RJournal_2010-2_Murdoch.pdf)) which allow RStudio to line up the code and execution point precisely.

I wasn't able to reproduce this with your example (it appears to reference a variable `m` that it doesn't declare); if you can resolve that and send it to me (jonathan at rstudio dot com) I'll see if we can improve the heuristics so this case works better.

Comment: @Johnathan I have now posted a simple example that exhibits this problem (As well as another problem with setting breakpoints) see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32015787/how-to-set-breakpoints-for-package-functions-in-rstudio