# How to set breakpoints for package functions in RStudio

Tags: r, rstudio

To replicate this error you must first install the package MARSS. I also include the user guide.

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/MARSS/vignettes/UserGuide.pdf

The example on page 35 can be called with the

```
dat = t(harborSealWA)
dat = dat[2:nrow(dat),]
debugonce(MARSSkem)
kemfit = MARSS(dat)
```

When debugmode is triggered for MARSSkem in RStudio, you will find that it is not possible to set breakpoints! There is also a debug message at the top of the screen saying: "Debug location is approximate because source source code is not available". I assume this is why I can't set the breakpoints!

The problem is the error I am trying to locate (which is not present in the simple example shown) is found on 55th iteration and each iteration includes several for loops with 100 loops each! To step though by hand is simply not practical!

Q1.) Is there a way to set breakpoints for this function in R studio?

Q2.) If not what is my best option to locate this problem? (Ideally I don't want to go messing around with the package source code but I will if its the only option)

Thanks

Baz

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to do this (I think) is to make your own copy of the function, source it, and then play around with breakpoints.

To do this:

```
View(MARSS)
```

You should see the source pop-up. Now copy paste it, into a new script with `mymarss <-` at the very start, save it (maybe as mymarss.R), and source it.

```
source(mymarss.R)
```

Now you can debug it like normal:

```
dat = t(harborSealWA)
dat = dat[2:nrow(dat),]
debugonce(mymarss)
kemfit = mymarss(dat)
```

And you can freely add/Remove breakpoints etc etc.

Comment: I like your idea but it gives: View(MARSS)
Error in View : cannot coerce class '"function"' into a data.frame

Comment: However I can just call it with debugonce: debugonce(MARSS) and use that to cut and paste it

Comment: weird, it works for me, but yes, you can also call `MARSS` with no arguments, or browse it to get its source

Comment: The function itself calls a couple of others but I can just repeat the processover renaming each function as my...

Answer (score 1):

From [Debugging with RStudio](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/205612627-Debugging-with-RStudio#debugging-in-packages)

> Breakpoints can be set in package code just as they can in free-standing R code. The primary difference is that you’ll need to have an up-to-date build of your package in order to set breakpoints. If your package build isn’t up to date, RStudio will warn you when you try to set a breakpoint.
>
> In order to debug effectively in your package, you’ll also want to ensure that your package is compiled with the --with-keep.source option. This option is the default for new packages in RStudio; if you need to set it manually, it can be found in Tools -> Project Options -> Build Tools.
>
> When a breakpoint is set in a file inside a package, RStudio will automatically disable the breakpoint when the package is unloaded and enable the breakpoint when the package is loaded. If you’re having trouble setting breakpoints in a package, make sure that the package was compiled with source information as described above and that its build is up-to-date.

I don't believe this works across R sessions. If you want to debug code which is calling a package function, you need to open the package file that contains the function *in the same session* as your calling code, and then set your breakpoint in the package function.