# Debugging package::function() although lazy evaluation is used

Tags: r, rstudio

How can I debug efficiently in R if packages are unknown due to lazy evaluation. I would like to keep the basic `browser()` functionality as it works great - even with the `testthat package`. As explained in the following [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31657555/strange-debug-results-in-r-studio), `--with-keep.source` is set for my project in "project options => Build Tools".

To reproduce the behavior, create a package `TestDebug` containing

```
myfun <- function(a,b) {return(a+b)}
```

and a script `example.R`

```
{
browser()
TestDebug::myfun(1,2)
}
```

**Edit**: The situation where `TestDebug::myfun(1,2)` calls `otherpackage::myfun2(1,2)` should be also covered. I think the situation should occur in every "real" package?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following works for me.

I have my package `TestDebug` with my function

`myfun <- function(a,b) {return(a+b)}`

If I run the script

```
debug(TestDebug::myfun)
TestDebug::myfun(1,2)
```

The debugger steps right into the source of `TestDebug::myfun()` not into the `::` function as it does when you place a `browser()` before the call to `TestDebug::myfun(1,2)`.

As you mention in your question: in real-life situations `TestDebug::myfun(1,2)` often calls `otherpackage::myfun2(1,2)`. If you try to step into `otherpackage::myfun2(1,2)` you will end up inside the `::` function again.

To prevent this I add this functions called inside other functions to the `debug` index on the fly:

As soon as you are on the line inside `TestDebug::myfun()` where `otherpackage::myfun2(1,2)` is called I run `debug(otherpackage::myfun2(1,2))` in the console. After that I can step into `otherpackage::myfun2(1,2)` without problems and end up in the source code of `otherpackage::myfun2(1,2)`. (..and not in the source code of `::`)

Don't forget to call `undebug(otherpackage::myfun2(1,2))` after you're sure that your problem is not inside `otherpackage::myfun2(1,2)` to prevent the debugger to jump into `otherpackage::myfun2(1,2)` the next time it is called.

If you prefer you can also use `debugonce(otherpackage::myfun(1,2))` (instead of `debug(..)`) to only debug a function once.

Comment: This solves the problem for my example. I realized that when you have a "real" package with more levels, e.g. `TestDebug::myfun(1,2)` calls `otherpackage::myfun2(1,2)` you run into the same problem again. See my edit of the question.

Comment: Your improved answer is at least a workaround. I still wonder, whether there are no more options. Somthing like a debug option `skip_base_functions` which could have the desired behavior.