# Debugging in RStudio

Tags: debugging, rstudio

If I use browser() function in a source file that is not in the current folder then RStudio complains that cannot find the file.

How can I instruct the debugger to find the source file where the breakpoint occurs?

Answer (score 1):

Place the function in `Desktop/testfun.R`:

```
fun <- function(a,b) {
  a <- 1
  b <- 2
  return(5)
}
```

Then the follwing works (You have to step into `fun()`):

```
{
  source("Desktop/testfun.R")
  browser()
  b <- fun(1,2)
}
```

If it is about debugging a package, have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37417395/debugging-packagefunction-although-lazy-evaluation-is-used)

Comment: Hi, thanks. But I don't know this apply to my case. The source files sometimes are part of a package that I have to debug so I prefer to keep the files in their current folders.

Comment: Thanks Christoph,  I think the debug() call could be a workaround but stiĺl not optimal. I would like to see more dobust debugging tools in future releases.

Comment: Please have a look at the link again - There are other people facing the same problems. Please consider to upvote useful questions / answers to show that the problem really exists...