# writeNIfTI failure - Error in if (!all(object@dim_[indices] > 0 & pixdim(object)[indices] > : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Tags: r, dicom, nifti

I am trying to write out a NIfTI file I created from DICOM images. For this example I am using a DICOM image from Kaggle's Data Science Bowl.

You have to accept the terms to download the example file, but it can be found here in the "stage1" folder:

https://www.kaggle.com/c/second-annual-data-science-bowl/data

```
pacman::p_load(oro.dicom, oro.nifti)
all_slices_fb99a80cbb2f441bb90135bab5b029fe <- readDICOM("stage1/fb99a80cbb2f441bb90135bab5b029fe")
nii_test <- dicom2nifti(all_slices_fb99a80cbb2f441bb90135bab5b029fe)
d=dim(nii_test); d; class(nii_test) #512 512 111
nii_test
```

> ```
> NIfTI-1 format
>   Type            : nifti
>   Data Type       : 4 (INT16)
>   Bits per Pixel  : 16
>   Slice Code      : 0 (Unknown)
>   Intent Code     : 0 (None)
>   Qform Code      : 2 (Aligned_Anat)
>   Sform Code      : 2 (Aligned_Anat)
>   Dimension       : 512 x 512 x 111
>   Pixel Dimension : 0.68 x 0.68 x NA
>   Voxel Units     : mm
>   Time Units      : sec
> ```

```
fname="output_3D_file"
writeNIfTI(nim=nii_test, filename=fname)
```

> ```
> Error in if (!all(object@dim_[indices] > 0 & pixdim(object)[indices] >  : 
>   missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
> ```

Comment: The `NA` looks strange `Pixel Dimension : 0.68 x 0.68 x NA`

Comment: @Christoph Yes, I'm not sure what it means or how / if to try to fix it, but when I look at the `str` there's a `@pixdim` field that says `@ pixdim        : num [1:8] -1 0.682 0.682 NA 1 ...`

Comment: I don't know the package. I would try to use `debug(package::writeNIfTI)` and then `writeNIfTI(nim=nii_test, filename=fname)`. I would hope to figure it out this way if nobody knows the error. It might be necessary to go through [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37432863/5784831)

Comment: @Christoph Thanks much, I will proceed down that path

Answer (score 0):

the exception is caused by the NA in Pixel Dimension

nii_test@pixdim[4] <- 1

will correct the Pixel Dimension to 0.68 x 0.68 x 1

after this step I was able to save the file.

Good Luck in the competition!